# Allow play rtmp from one site (nginx with rtmp module)

Tags: linux, nginx, live, vps, rtmp

is there any way to deny users play my stream on other sites? I'm running nginx with rtmp module, ubuntu 13. Here is my ngingx.conf

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        allow publish 89.79.80.40;
        allow publish 89.74.42.165;
        deny publish all;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use basic allow, deny policy to build your own whitelist please read [nginx-rtmp-module wiki](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#allow)
for more information.

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        allow publish 89.79.80.40;
        allow publish 89.74.42.165;
        deny publish all;

        allow play 89.79.80.40;
        allow play 89.74.42.165;
        deny play all;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
        }
    }
}
```